# Update a ManyToMany Relationship Through the Inverse Side in Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

My recipe entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="recipes")
 */
private $categories;
```

My Category entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Recipe", inversedBy="categories")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="recipe_category")
 */
private $recipes;
```

Ok this is from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPrgoe3Jrjw&feature=related.

With this two owning sides all works fine. But the cli gives the error: 'The table with name recipe_category already exists. Does anyone have any idea's how the best practice?

Comment: What do you mean by "cli gives the error" ? Does this happen when you just "php app/console", or "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" ... ?

Comment: I mean php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Answer (score 1):

You have to update de other entity like :

```
class Recipe
{
    public function addCategory($cat)
    {
        $car->addRecipe($this);
        $this->categories->add($cat);

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory($cat)
    {
        $cat->removeRecipe($this);
        $this->categories->removeElement($cat);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your both sides are "inversedBy", that is incorrect ...

You should read this tuto : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/saving-inverse-side-collection

And in particular see the conclusion : "this situation has caused many developers to lose countless hours trying to get their relationship to save. To summarize: if you're modifying the inverse side of a relationship, set the by_reference form option to false, create an adder and remover function, and make sure you set the owning side of the relationship in each"